# Запись аудио с микрофона

Tags: c#, windows, ubuntu, mono

Стоит задача: написать кроссплатформенное приложение, язык с#, в подробности задачи углубляться не буду, но основа для приложения — это считать поток аудио с микрофона.

Сразу начал писать под windows (на VS12), тут проблем не возникло, использовал библиотеку naudio, позже решил запустить на ubuntu, погуглил и наткнулся на mono, где и столкнулся/узнал, что методы naudio работают посредством доступом к Windows API.

Как реализовать запись звука с помощью mono?

Comment: Может с http://www.mono-project.com/Gstreamer что-нибудь выйдет?

Comment: может примеры какие видели... именно процесса записи/захвата потока с микрофона

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать [си-шарп привязку к библиотеке gstreamer](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/gstreamer/).

примеры использования есть в каталоге `samples` в исходниках, которые можно скачать по указанной ссылке.